# Three INNER JOINs for 4 tables, some values may or may not be null in query

Tags: mysql

On one of the pages of my site, I am using an inner join on 4 tables (login, stats, poll, and announce) as follows:

```
$login_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_SESSION['user']);

$sqlAll = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, 
    "SELECT login.picture, login.statement,
    stats.wealth,
    MAX(poll.polltime) AS pollunixtime,
    MAX(announce.announcetime) AS announceunixtime 
    FROM login 
    INNER JOIN stats ON login.user = stats.user 
    INNER JOIN poll ON login.user = poll.user 
    INNER JOIN announce ON login.user = announce.source 
    WHERE (login.user = '$login_user' AND announce.announcetype = 'feedback')"));
```

This inner join works fine as long as at least one row in the table **announce** and one row in the table **poll** is populated for that user, e.g., this form input's value is defined:

```
<form id="myForm"><input type="hidden" name="wealth" value="<?= $sqlAll['wealth'] ?>"></form>//"View Page Source" shows this value is defined and shows up as value="number"
```

However, I noticed that when there is no row exists for either table for a user, the query fails in that certain values from the query are undefined. For example, if no rows for either table, the value of this form input is undefined:

```
<form id="myForm"><input type="hidden" name="wealth" value="<?= $sqlAll['wealth'] ?>"></form>//"View Page Source" shows this value is undefined and shows up as value=""
```

I tried introducing CASE into my query in a variety of ways, for example:

```
$sqlAll = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, 
    "SELECT login.picture, login.statement,
     stats.wealth,
     MAX(poll.polltime) AS pollunixtime,
     MAX(announce.announcetime) AS announceunixtime
     FROM login
     INNER JOIN stats ON login.user = stats.user
     INNER JOIN poll ON CASE WHEN poll.polltime IS NOT NULL THEN login.user = poll.user END 
     INNER JOIN announce ON CASE WHEN announce.announcetime IS NOT NULL THEN login.user = announce.source END 
     WHERE (login.user = '$login_user' AND announce.announcetype = 'feedback')"));
```

Since polltime and announcetime are of type INT, I also tried to use ">" as follows:

```
$sqlAll = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, 
    "SELECT login.picture, login.statement,
    stats.wealth,
    MAX(poll.polltime) AS pollunixtime,
    MAX(announce.announcetime) AS announceunixtime 
    FROM login
    INNER JOIN stats ON login.user = stats.user 
    INNER JOIN poll ON CASE WHEN poll.polltime > 0 THEN login.user = poll.user END    
    INNER JOIN announce ON CASE WHEN announce.announcetime > 0 THEN login.user = announce.source END 
    WHERE (login.user = '$login_user' AND announce.announcetype = 'feedback')"));
```

I also tried variations where the CASE statement was placed with **poll** and **announce** as follows:

```
$sqlAll = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, 
    "SELECT login.picture, login.statement, 
     stats.wealth, 
     CASE WHEN MAX(poll.polltime) IS NOT NULL THEN 'pollunixtime' END, 
     CASE WHEN MAX(announce.announcetime) IS NOT NULL THEN 'announceunixtime' END 
     FROM login 
     INNER JOIN stats ON login.user = stats.user 
     INNER JOIN poll ON login.user = poll.user 
     INNER JOIN announce ON login.user = announce.source 
     WHERE (login.user = '$login_user' AND announce.announcetype = 'feedback')"));
```

No variation I have tried has worked. Basically, I need a CONDITIONAL INNER JOIN such that the 2nd and 3rd inner joins are performed if polltime and announcetime both exist for a given user, else the 2nd and 3rd inner joins are not performed. Is this possible?

**Please note that I already have a hack solution, which in this system involves breaking up the one query above into 3 separate queries and use ISSET to test for the existence of polltime and announcetime for a given user.** I would like to do better than this solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something somewhat similar to what you're asking by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: But does LEFT JOIN account for null values?

Comment: Suppose we changed your query to say `LEFT JOIN stats ON login.user = stats.user LEFT JOIN poll ON login.user = poll.user LEFT JOIN announce ON login.user = announce.source`. What that means is that your `login` rows will all be there, regardless of whether a corresponding row exists in `stats`, `poll`, or `announce`. Does that sound like what you want to do?